# PlayFramework 2.3.x How to use websockets to both broadcast to all and to specific clients

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

**UPDATE**
This was answered here @
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/P-tG6b_SEyg
**--**

First Play/Scala app here and I am struggling a bit. What I am trying to achieve is collaboration between users on specific channels (websocket urls). I am trying to follow the example from the book "Play Framework Essentials" and trying to adapt to my use case. Depending on the request from the client, I would either like to broadcast the information to all the clients talking on this channel or only send information back to the client that sent the initial request. The broadcast part is working but I am unable to figure out how to send the information back to just the client of the request themselves.

In my controller I have

```
def ws(channelId: String) = WebSocket.tryAccept[JsValue] { implicit request =>
  getEnumerator(channelId).map { out =>
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue] { jsMsg =>
      val id = (jsMsg \ "id").as[String]
      // This works and broadcasts that the user has connected
      connect(id, request.session.get("email").get)
      // Not sure how to return the result of this just to the client of the request
      retrieve(id)
    }
    Right((in, out))
  }
}

private def getEnumerator(id: String): Future[Enumerator[JsValue]] = {
  (myActor ? GetEnumerator(id)).mapTo[Enumerator[JsValue]]
}

private def connect(id: String, email: String): Unit = {
  (myActor ! Connect(id, email))
}

// I have a feeling this is an incorrect return type and I need to return a Future[JsValue]    
//and somehow feed that to the enumerator
private def retrieve(id: String): Future[Enumerator[JsValue]] = {
  (myActor ? RetrieveInfo(id)).mapTo[Enumerator[JsValue]]
}
```

In my Actor

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  var communicationChannels = Map.empty[String, CommunicationChannel]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetEnumerator(id) => sender() ! getOrCreateCommunicationChannel(id).enumerator
    case Connect(id, email) => getOrCreateCommunicationChannel(id).connect(email)
    case RetrieveInfo(id) => sender() ! Json.toJson(Info(id, "details for " + id))
  }


  private def getOrCreateCommunicationChannel(id: String): CommunicationChannel = {
    communicationChannels.getOrElse(id, {
      val communicationChannel = new CommunicationChannel
      communicationChannels += id -> communicationChannel
      communicationChannel
    })
  }
}

object MyActor {

  def props: Props = Props[MyActor]

  class CommunicationChannel {
    val (enumerator, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]

    def connect(email: String) = {
      channel.push(Json.toJson(Connected(email)))
    }
  }
}
```

Where Connect, Connected, Info etc are just case classes with Reads and Writes defined

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to push message to specific user(s) with this approach rather than broadcast it to everyone? Or if I need to implement this in another way

Also is there a way to broadcast to everyone except yourself

Any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks!!